# jQuery: just show/hide and not slideIn/Out

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a tabbed navigation, here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/) . For now the contens slidesUp/Down but I want it just to disappear/appear. Any Ideas?

```
  // When the document loads do everything inside here ...
  $(document).ready(function(){

    // When a link is clicked
        $("a.tab").click(function () {              

            // switch all tabs off
            $(".active").removeClass("active");

            // switch this tab on
            $(this).addClass("active");

            // slide all content up
            $(".content").slideUp();

            // slide this content up
            var content_show = $(this).attr("title");
            $("#"+content_show).slideDown();

        });

      });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace

```
$(".content").slideUp();
```

with

```
$(".content").hide();
```

and

```
$("#"+content_show).slideDown();
```

with

```
$("#"+content_show).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

or

```
$(".content").fadeOut();
```

and

```
$("#"+content_show).fadeIn();
```